# Pycharm видит только глобальные пакеты

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm

При создании проекта в PyCharm создаю новую `venv`(`inherit global site-packages` активна), используя `virtualenv`. При старте запускается терминал с припиской `venv`, но `pip list` выводит список глобальных пакетов, а не локальных. При использовании `pip install` пакеты устанавливаются только глобально.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если в терминале  ввести `deactivate`, а затем запустить файл `activate.bat` из папки `venv\Scripts`, запустится `venv`, в которой `pip list` будет отображать локальные пакеты(т.е. то, что нужно).

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При открытии еще одного окна в терминале, pycharm опять видит только глобальные пакеты:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Интерпретатор при этом не меняется:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Через `Project Interpetator` я могу устанавливать пакеты, но при запуске скрипта через `python filename.py` ошибка `ModuleNotFoundError`. Через `deactivate`, `activate.bat` и запуске скрипта - ошибки не будет.

Собственно вопрос - как сделать так, чтобы при запуске Pycharm сразу видел локальные пакеты, а не глобальные.

Comment: Что показывает команда `echo %PATH%` в этих двух случаях?

Comment: @RomanKonoval показывает идентичные пути. `...D\ПВГ\venv\Scripts\; C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\Scripts\;...` есть в обоих случаях

Answer (score 1):

Это происходит потому, что у вас не включена опция автоматической активации virtual env-a в терминале.

Включается это в `Settings (Preferences) | Tools | Terminal`:

[image: Активация виртуального окружения в терминале PyCharm]

Так как опция не включена, то у вас используется глобальный питон и приходится делать ручную активацию.

Comment: Опция включена. При запуске PyCharm терминал запускается с виртуальной средой, но как-то криво.

Answer (score 0):

Столкнулся примерно с такой же проблемой. По итогу понял что виртуальное окружение нужно создавать через команду

```
python -m venv [имя окружения]
```

После этого PyCharm нормально стал воспринимать окружение. При деактивации выдавал глобальные пакеты, а при активации пакеты виртуального окружения. А вот если создавать виртуальное окружение через PyCharm, то возникает проблема и при команде `pip list` выдает только глобальные пакеты.

Также почему-то если использовать powershell в терминале, то возникают проблемы. В настройках я переключил на cmd